# building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

Tags: swift, realm

Getting this error.

Realm/core/librealmcore-ios.a(array_binary.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

Swift iOS 14 xcode 12.0.1

What I have tried :

- Updating to the latest realm
- Excluding the arm64 architecture

Nothing seems to work
Seems realm are having issues too : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cocoapods

"Arm64 simulator architecture may not be supported for several combinations of Realm 5.x and Xcode 12. Please attempt the following workarounds if you experience architecture-related build errors with the latest version of Realm."

Comment: Which version of cocoapods are you using?

Comment: Not sure what that link in the question is for but I just created a new project, same set up as you, used Cocoapods to install RealmSwift and it's up and running. Can you include your podfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was

setting the BuildActiveArchitectureOnly to Yes in the build settings.

And

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      end
    end
```

And

Updated my Realm to the latest version.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.5.0'
```

They already added support for xcframework.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a proper fix, but what worked for my project is:

- following the suggestions provided by: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cocoapods
- Installing cocoapods 1.10.0.rc1
- setting the `BuildActiveArchitectureOnly` to `Yes` in the cocoapods project

Now when you build your app for your device or you're archiving make sure to set this back to `No`, or alternatively, use a different config for this (e.g: I have `Debug` set to `Yes`, `Release` to `No`).